# How to transform or map a json to a specific json format

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON payload which i want to transform or map to another JSON payload.

```
source = {
    'customer': {
        'first_name': 'Inigo',
        'last_name': 'Montoya',
        'Age': 24,
    },
    'address': {
        'city': 'Sicily',
        'country': 'Florin',
    },
}
```

Output should be:

```
{"fullName": "Inigo Montoya", "city": "Sicily"}
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far for it

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import json

source = {
    'customer': {
        'first_name': 'Inigo',
        'last_name': 'Montoya',
        'Age': 24,
    },
    'address': {
        'city': 'Sicily',
        'country': 'Florin',
    },
}


def make_res_payload(source):
      fullName = "{} {}".format(source['customer']['first_name'], source['customer']['last_name'])
      city = source['address']['city']
      res = dict({ 'fullName': fullName, 'city': city })
      return json.dumps(res)

res = make_res_payload(source)

print(res)
```

Outputting:

```
{"fullName": "Inigo Montoya", "city": "Sicily"}
```